# Transform an array to an object with respective index as key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

It's a very simple question but I didn't found any answer or function for such a case. I have a simple array:

```
["Desc1", "Desc2", "Desc3", "Desc4", "Desc5"]
```

I want transform it to an object like that:

```
{0: "Desc1", 1: "Desc2", 2: "Desc3", 3: "Desc4", 4: "Desc5"}
```

I can use Lodash but not ES6

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How come? Is there something the object can do that the array can't?

Comment: It already **is** an object like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a simple one-liner.

```js
const a = ["Desc1", "Desc2", "Desc3", "Desc4", "Desc5"];

const r = Object.assign({}, a);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Should we not allow OP to share effort? Answering without effort promotes spoon-feeding

Comment: The apparently numeric keys of the array are really strings internally.

Comment: @Pointy So it's fine to keep it this way, actually? Anyways, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Do with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
function .Add the index with key of the object

```js
var arr =["Desc1", "Desc2", "Desc3", "Desc4", "Desc5"];
var obj={};

arr.forEach(function(a,b){
obj[b]=a
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a)

```js
var output = ["Desc1", "Desc2", "Desc3", "Desc4", "Desc5"].reduce( function(a,b,i){ 
   ( a = typeof a == "string" ? {[i-1] : a} : a ), a[i] = b;
   return a; 
});
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr =["Desc1", "Desc2", "Desc3", "Desc4", "Desc5"];
var obj = arr.reduce(function(accumulator,  currentvalue, currentindex){
   accumulator[currentindex]=currentvalue;
   return accumulator;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: @Rajesh thanks fixed :-). Was typing it out on my phone without a REPL earlier

Answer (score 0):

What about applying the forEach() method on the array?

```js
var obj = {} // declaring an empty object
var array = ["Desc1", "Desc2", "Desc3", "Desc4", "Desc5"] // storing the array in a variable
array.forEach(function(item, index) {
  obj[index + 1] = item; // storing the item in a property with the corresponding number
});
console.log(obj);
```

Hope that answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for of` loop with an index counter.

```js
var array = ["Desc1", "Desc2", "Desc3", "Desc4", "Desc5"],
    i = 0;
    object = {};

for (object[i++] of array);

console.log(object);
```